# BIML SCD component

Tags: ssis, scd, biml

In SSIS we have the basic SCD component to refresh Dimension tables.
I was looking to use it via BIML, but the component does not seem to exist...
Is there a way in BIML to refresh a Dim ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use the SSIS SCD component, it doesn't support all standard SCD features, it's slow, and it only has a 'destructive edit'. You can manually build the SCD concept out of many different pieces, but again, it's very inefficient. All of my SCD's are done using staging tables and updates/inserts

Comment: you mean it'd be better to use a SQL merge statement instead of using built in SCD component ? 
If you have an example in BIML just drop :)
Thanks

Comment: Personally I just use separate `INSERT` and `UPDATE`. However I do acknowledge that piecing together SSIS components in BIML is easier than piecing together a SQL statement.

Comment: The scd **wizard** in SSIS is special in that it really doesn't exist. Behind the scenes, it generates ssis components based on your selections. That's why when you make a change to the source you have to regenerate the scd components. In biml, you own the implementation of the scd so you're directing how the pieces should fit together

Comment: So basically a merge handling all the cases New/changed/deleted records
is better then ?
I am just looking for a way to generate a merge based on metadata with BIML... if one of you guys have an example, would be great !

Comment: You generally don't delete records in a SCD. I've never used BIML I just know what it does. If you have 100 flat files that are required to feed a SCD then it might be worth investigating BIML to generate an SCD step for you. If you have three or four sources you're better of hand coding it. The thing is, building a dimension normally requires some level of manual mapping so BIML is of no use there. Anyway IMHO, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` are far more efficient than the SCD for large amounts of records, but obviously they have a lot of code.

Comment: If you wanted to rely on SSIS components and avoid the SQL Merge, you can use `lookups` per [this](https://benefic.net/ssis-alternatives-to-the-scd-transform/) writeup.